Integral Formula for length of rectifiable (not $C^1$) curve proof
Suppose $\gamma:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^N$ is a rectifiable (not necessarily $C^1$!) curve. I want to show that one still has the integral formula for the length of $\gamma$: $L(\gamma)=\int_a^b |\gamma'(t)|dt$. The length itself is defined as $L(\gamma):=\sup\sum_{k=1}^K |\gamma(x_k)-\gamma(x_{k-1})|$, where the supremum is taken over all partitions $a=x_0<x_1<\dots<x_K=b$ of the interval.
I already know that for $C^1$ functions, is there any way to use that knowledge to get it for just rectifiable curves, too? By an approximation argument? Using $\gamma$ is Lipschitz (follows from rectifiability) one gets almost everywhere differentiability (by Rademacher), however I am not able to use that successfully.
